# Echo string that contains words concatenated without using array-PHP

Tags: php, string, loops, echo

I have a string which comprises of the words the user input in it so I don't know how many words will be there and what will be the index of each word so that I can find substring out of this. Can anyone tell me how to echo it without using or converting it into array and add next line whenever there is space in string. I am newbie to php. I checked for split method, explode method, all inbuilt methods are converting it into array which i dont need.

```
$var= "This is a sample code."
```

I want output like this:

```
This
is 
a
sample 
code
```

I tried this but it didnt work for me.

```
$count= str_word_count($var);
        echo "$count";
        $strlen= strlen($var);
        for($i=0; $i<(int)$strlen;$i++ ){
          if($var contains " "){
          echo "\n";
        }else {
          echo $var;
        }
        }
```

I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Um... What is your reason for not allowing arrays? I'm your case can you not just `str_replace` spaces with new lines?

Comment: Can you provide some code.I m trying to use str_replace

Comment: Just take a look at the [documentation](http://php.net/str_replace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Without other builtin functions and just using `for` loop , This will give the expected output**

```
 for($i=0; $i<(int)$strlen;$i++ ){
          if($var[$i]==" "){
          echo "<br>";
        }else if($var[$i] !='.'){
          echo $var[$i];
        }
  }
```

Comment: Here $var[i] willact as string or array ?

Comment: we get each character as `$var[$i]`.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. Your solution worked for me but I am in doubt whether $var[i] is treated as array or string.

Comment: each string is an array of chars , actually what is the problem with **arrays**.

Comment: Because I have to implement it without using array.

Comment: I just corrected your code in the question , still don't get what you are expecting . Anyway the `str_replace` will do this in single line .

Comment: I dont know but it is throwing exception in that case if I am using str_replace.Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function str_repalce() in file

Comment: yeah , you need to change `str_repalce()` to `str_replace()` . It's a typo.

Comment: yeah I got it and both ways are correct. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use [`str_replace()`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
echo str_replace(" ", "\n", $var);
```

but you also can perform *regular expression*, that can give you maybe a better answer, it will be able to check only words, ignoring multiple spaces or other space characters.

```
$var= "This is a         sample   code.";
if ( preg_match_all("/(\w+)/si", $var, $m ) ){
    echo implode("\n", $m[1]);
}
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function str_repalce() in example.php:17 I got this error

Comment: I did a typo in the example code, i haven't done any typo in link. Plese go and read docs. Regular expressions explained on PCRE  page ( https://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php ).